# Code conflicts on various SQL Server versions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a code that inserts a row 100 times. The problem is, my code works on SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2012, but not in 2005. I need to make it work with 2005, too.

Here's my code:

```
DECLARE @ctr as INT = 1
WHILE @ctr < 128
BEGIN
INSERT INTO DftRoleModulePermissions (
    RoleId,
    ModuleName,
    CanView,
    CanEdit,
    IsActive,
    UTCDateCreated,
    UTCDateModified,
    StampUserName 
    )
VALUES (
    @ctr,
    'Schedules',
    1,
    1,
    1,
    GetUTCDate(),
    GetUTCDate(),
    ''
    )
SET @ctr += 1
END
```

Comment: Does this code give you any errors on 2005? If so: ***what*** errors?

Comment: Must declare a scalar variable @ctr and cannot assign a default value to local variable

Comment: If you must make code work for a lower version of software it is irresponsible to develop on a higher version. Why didn't you do all your devlopement on SQL server 2005?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change variable declaration:

```
DECLARE @ctr as INT;
set @ctr = 1;
```

and counter increment at end of loop to:

```
Set @ctr = @ctr + 1
```

Comment: Ditto for `@ctr += 1` iirc (change to `set @ctr = @ctr + 1`)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that in lower versions, you must do all decalaration and assignments like this. New knowledge acquired!